# Dynamic Bin folders hard to copy bin folder to artifact location Azure DevOps

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I have a problem with my CI in Azure DevOps.

I need to have a generic PowerShell script run in each CI that copy files from the bin folder and put them to artifact(a) folder with each project folder name.

But bin path are dynamic e.g.

```
$projectBinDirectory\bin\release\net471\win-x64
$projectBinDirectory\bin\release\net471
$projectBinDirectory\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\win-x64
$projectBinDirectory\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\win-x64
$projectBinDirectory\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1
```

in the future, if someone creates netcore 2.2 or something else how to configure publish path dynamically as I want to copy main project files

e.g.
copy from

```
bin\release\netcoreapp2.1\win-x64 all project *.dlls,*configs etc files
```

to

```
artifact\Projectname\ all project files
```

the issue
cannot figure out after bin\release\ path to reach to project files

I need to figure out what is the path dynamically after bin\release...\projectFiles

Comment: I use publish Profiles too but still, the issue is same.
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\Publish</PublishDir>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>true</_IsPortable>

Answer (score 0):

this argument fixed my issue 
-c Release -o ./bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/publishNew:

[image]